# string formatting with modulus/percent sign

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting, modulus

Is there something happening when string formatting that uses the modulus function while calling either

`StringOperand % TupleOperand` or

`StringOperand % DictionaryOperand`

Or is it just an arbitrary use of % for the string formatting function?

I'm guessing that the string formatting operator is not a call to modular arithmetic as the following:

```
tuple = (1,2,3)
print '%d %d %d'%tuple
```

prints: 1 2 3, but

```
print '%d %d %d %d'%tuple
```

returns TypeError: not enough args for format str

Comment: This is called *operator overloading* and is common in python.  A class can implement an operator to mean anything it likes by implementing a special method, in this case `__mod__()`.  For example, try `print "hello" * 3`.  See  also https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [operator overloading](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/operator-overloading-python). What you are talking about is language build-in, but you may overload methods on your own. Eg overload `+` operator that is decorated in python by `__add__` method:

```
class YourMath(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

    def __add__(self, x):
        return int(str(self.param) + str(x.param)) # concatenation 


x = YourMath(5)
y = YourMath(4)
```

`+` will concatenate instead of sum up. 
Result of `x+y` in this case is `54`.

Comment: Is this an example of operator overloading as well: "import math as m"?

Comment: No "import math as m" is import of `math` module with alias `m`